# Specifying Arguments of MATLAB functions in Python

Tags: python, matlab, arguments

How do I speficy the argument key followed by the argument when calling a MATLAB function within Python?

For example the [kurtosis](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/kurtosis.html#d123e502513) function accepts arguments `X`, `flag`, `dim` and `vecdim`. But when I try to specify `X=x_matrix` as below, I get an error:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
x_matrix = np.random.rand(3,2)
x_matrix = matlab.double(x_matrix.tolist())
ans = eng.kurtosis(X=x_matrix, flag=1) 

## TypeError: invalid keyword argument 'X'
```

It works fine if I just pass the arguments in order:

```
x_matrix = np.random.rand(3,2)
x_matrix = matlab.double(x_matrix.tolist())
ans = eng.kurtosis(x_matrix, 1)

## matlab.double([[1.4999999999999996,1.4999999999999991]])
```

(Just using kurtosis as a simple example, but applies to all other functions, too).

Thank you.

Comment: Likely the MATLAB engine does not support keyword arguments, and thats it. Its proprietary, so you won't be able to change it. I guess you can always write your own wrappers to the functions that you like.

Comment: Just to clarify further I guess: MATLAB (until the next version that comes up) does not have support for kyeyword type arguments, it just takes everything in order as it comes. This is a very common thing. Its very likely that the MATLAB engine just directly calls MATLAB code, and there is no intermediate stage that parses the inputs, thus it makes sense that they don allow python keyword arguments

Comment: @AnderBiguri I found that if the function documentation page says you can have multiple name values pairs, for example templateTree(), then you can put the argument name in quotes and the value after a comma. But, ye for the above example, it doesn't seem easy to do for now. Thanks for replying though!

example = eng.templateTree("MaxNumSplits",1,"Surrogate","on","MergeLeaves","off")

Comment: Yes, that is the standard way for unordered optional variables in MATLAB (not keyword arguments). But generally only applies for the optional arguments, and as long as the MATLAB function accepts this format.